# Browser shows redirect loop for homepage, but posts open just fine

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Solved: Clearing Cloudflare cache helped. That's the last thing that I would try lol.

My site has a weird issue right now. While opening the homepage, the browser gives too many redirects error, but the other posts and pages open just fine.

I am scratching my head since morning trying to figure out the issue, but I am unable to.

Please help me.

I am using ReallySimpleSSL plugin with Cloudflare for SSL if that matters.

Comment: what do you mean by redirect loop for homepage ?

Comment: Hi, please check the URL, I mean too many redirects issue.

Comment: I can open your homepage just fine, no redirect loop. It could be a conditional loop that only affects your machine or users that are logged in e.g. in case you have a certain value in your cookie or something like that.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić, Hi, that's weird. Can you open the https version?

Comment: @IgorJerosimić, you were right, I just tried opening my site from my Windows VPS (a different IP address) and both the versions work fine. Although the http version isn't being redirected to https (only for homepage), but post pages are being redirected just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your html `<head>` section, you have a couple of links do not have `https:` specified. You may also have some mix content (particularly image that might still in `http:`, I didn't check for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The site was working fine (including the homepage) the last week I checked it, but all of a sudden this happens. So, I am sure that there is no plugin messing things up for me to troubleshoot.